# How to disable sorting but allow filtering on DVWP

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, data-view-web-part

I want to disable sorting but allow filtering on DVWP.

I have struggled much for it but not able to get rid of it. If I pass 0 in sortable then it takes away both filter and sorting from context menu.

```
<xsl:call-template name="dvt.headerfield" ddwrt:atomic="1" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldname">@Title</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtitle">Title</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="displayname">Title</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="sortable">1</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype">x:string</xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
```

Please suggest how can i achieve this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Find the

```
<xsl:template name="dvt.headerfield">
```

Add a parameter

```
<xsl:param name="filterable">1</xsl:param>
```

Find the <table and remove the onmouseover attribute

under the <table tag, add

```
<xsl:if test="$filterable=1">
    <xsl:attribute name="onmouseover">OnMouseOverAdHocFilter(this, '{concat($displayname,$separator,$fieldname, $separator,$fieldtype, $connector, 1033, $separator, $dvt_partguid)}')</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```